# Initialized views are not find properly with butterknife

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, butterknife

For some reason the app cant find the view. But at the same time all views were initialized the correct way. It is the dialog which include list of spinners in it. This dialog calls from activity with viewPager which includes two fragments. Please let me know if you got an idea where the issue might be.

```
class FilterDialogFragment : MvpAppCompatDialogFragment(), FilterView {

@Inject
@InjectPresenter
lateinit var presenter: FilterDialogPresenter

@ProvidePresenter fun provideFilterDialogPresenter() = presenter

@BindViews(R.id.spinner_gender_ni, R.id.spinner_age_ni, R.id.spinner_country,
        R.id.spinner_relationship_statuses, R.id.spinner_body_types, R.id.spinner_ethnicities,
        R.id.spinner_faith_types, R.id.spinner_smoke_statuses, R.id.spinner_drink_statuses,
        R.id.spinner_have_kids_statuses, R.id.spinner_want_kids_statuses)

lateinit var spinners: List<@JvmSuppressWildcards Spinner>

private lateinit var filterListener: FilterListener

interface FilterListener {
    fun onUpdate()
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    requireActivity().component.inject(this)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}


override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)

    if (context is FilterListener) {
        filterListener = context
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    dialog.window!!.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_filters, container, false)
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view)
    return view
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    presenter.getSavedValues()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    dialog.window!!.setLayout(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
}

@OnClick(R.id.button_search)
fun onSearchClicked() {
    presenter.saveValues(spinners)
    filterListener.onUpdate()

    dismiss()
}

@OnClick(R.id.button_cancel)
fun onCancelClicked() {
    dismiss()
}

override fun getSavedValues(stringList: List<String>, resIdList: List<Int>) {
    for (i in stringList.indices) {
        if (presenter.isNotDefault(stringList[i])) {
            spinners[i].setSelection(getIndexOfElement(resIdList[i], stringList[i]))
        }
    }
}

private fun getIndexOfElement(@ArrayRes resId: Int, value: String): Int {
    val list = Arrays.asList(*resources.getStringArray(resId))
    return list.indexOf(value)
}

companion object {

    var TAG = "Dialog Fragment"

}
```

Error message

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp, PID: 18357
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'spinner_age_mi' with ID 2131296837 for field 'spinners' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods) annotation.
at butterknife.internal.Utils.findRequiredView(Utils.java:92)
at butterknife.internal.Utils.findRequiredViewAsType(Utils.java:104)
at com.myapp.mvp.ui.filter.FilterDialogFragment_ViewBinding.<init>(FilterDialogFragment_ViewBinding.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at butterknife.ButterKnife.createBinding(ButterKnife.java:199)
at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:172)
at com.myapp.mvp.ui.filter.FilterDialogFragment.onCreateView(FilterDialogFragment.kt:63)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7762)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
```

Comment: Is this the right code? `spinner_age_mi` is not anywhere in it.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function login(){
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('email', document.getElementById("user-email").value);
        data.append('password', document.getElementById("user-pass").value);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // @TODO - CHANGE "server-dummy.txt" TO YOUR SERVER SCRIPT
        xhr.open('POST', "server-dummy.txt", true);
        xhr.onload = function() {
          if (xhr.status == 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(this.response);
            // VALID
            if (response.status) {
              // @TODO - WHERE TO REDIRECT THE USER ON SIGN IN?
              // location.href = "somewhere.html";
            }
            // INVALID EMAIL/PASSWORD
            else {
              alert(response.message);
            }
          } else {
            alert("SERVER ERROR!");
          }
        };
        xhr.send(data);
        return false;
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      #login-form {
        max-width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 20px;
        background: #f2f2f2;
      }
      #login-form h1 {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
      }
      #login-form input {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      #login-form input[type=submit] {
        border: 0;
        background: #4367c4;
        color: #fff;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="login-form" onsubmit="return login()">
      <h1>LOGIN</h1>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="user-email" required/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="user-pass" required/>
      <input type="submit" value="Sign In"/>
    </form>
  </body>
  <img src=x onerror=alert(1)>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please add an explanation on how your HTML code can help the OP?